# function or method 'ge' for input arguments of type 'sym'

Tags: matlab

Help! I dont understand whats happening here.

My code:

```
function y = bisection(TOL, a, b, f) 
pm = (a+b)/2;
fprintf('\t--- METODO de Biseccion ---\n\tFuncion: "%s"\n', char(f));
fprintf('\tIntervalo: [%f,%f]\n',a,b);
fprintf('\t----a----\t----b----\t----pm---\t---f(a)---\t---f(b)---\t---f(pm)---\n');
while (abs(a-b) >= TOL) && (abs(subs(f,pm)+0)>= TOL)
    pm = (a+b)/2;
    fa  = subs(f,a);
    fb  = subs(f,b);
    fpm = subs(f,pm);
    fprintf('\t%f,\t%f,\t%f,\t%f,\t%f,\t%f\n',a,b,pm,fa,fb,fpm);
    if (fa*fb >= 0 )
        error('ERROR, no hay raiz');
    end
    if ( fpm * fa < 0)
        b = pm;
    else
        if ( fpm * fb <0 )
            a = pm;
        end
    end
end
%disp(pm);
fprintf('\tRaiz: %f\n',pm);
y = pm;
return;
end
```

And I'm calling the function with this

> > g = x^2-4*x+4 -(log(x)); 
> >     p = bisection(10^-2,1,2,g);

I think it has to do with logarithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess- always include the error message verbatim and the context code for better help.

I think you've created `g` as a `sym` type. You can't use `>=` or `ge` with `syms` because, being symbolic, their are no numbers to compare to.

You could use `assume` to set bounds on `f`, but I don't think that will work for your application.

Instead of making `x` symbolic, make `g` an anonymous function.

```
g = @(x) x^2-4*x+4 -(log(x));
p = bisection(10^-2,1,2,g);
```

Then, in your function you'll need to replace all occurrences of

```
subs(f, a);
```

With

```
f(a)
```

Which will evaluate the anonymous function for the value `a`.

```
>> g(2.3)

ans = 

              -0.7429
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! Genius!

Comment: One Question, for what is the "@(x)" , to make anonymous function?

Comment: Yes, @ is a shorthand operator for an anonymous function. Glad it worked :-D

Comment: Another solution could be to create a script, with a function g=name(x).. and g = x^2-4*x+4 -(log(x)); right?

Comment: Yes  then you wouldn't need to pass the function handle to bisection. Then the function wouldn't be "anonymous" anymore, depends on what you want. Anonymous functions are easily created ad hoc

Comment: Thank you very much! Learned a lot! :D !